# Can i use LibGDX to program a VR game with the Oculus Rift + touch?

Tags: libgdx, virtual-reality, oculus

Can i use LibGDX to program a VR game with the Oculus Rift + touch? I just got an oculus rift + touch controllers and would like to code a game. I am very familiar with LibGDX and would like to stay using that as the game engine. Is this possible and if so, how?